# CSS3 opacity transition not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I've got a super-simple CSS3 transition: just an image that fades out.

It works in all browsers except Safari (tested on Safari 8.0.7). What am I missing?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nerdess/9Lambqan/

Here is the code:

```css
.fade {
    background: url(https://placeimg.com/200/100) no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
   from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="fade"></div>
```

(I know that there are various stackoverflow posts aleady dealing with this topic but none had an answer that helped me!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-webkit-keyframes`

```css
.fade {
    background: url(https://placeimg.com/200/100) no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
   from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
   from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="fade"></div>
```

Take a look at this css-tricks page to view all compatibility as possible.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: thanks! this worked! thanks also for the link to css-tricks, now i understand what is going on :)